# Asp GridView prepended localhost when clicking on the link

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I am using `asp:GridView`. I have a field with hyperlink in it. I must be able to update that link (by clicking on `'edit'`) and also to connect web site, which link is providing, when I click on the link. Everything works fine, except when I click on the link, I've got `localhost` prepended. So, if my link is: `www.google.com`, with click on the link I am redirected to `localhost:8080/www.google.com`. How to get rid of prepended localhost?

My code below:

```
<asp:BoundField 
DataField="CUSTOMER"
HtmlEncode="False"  
DataFormatString="<a target='_blank' href='{0}'>{0}</a>"
HeaderText="Customer - link" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this will work for you

```
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField
            DataField="CUSTOMER"
            HtmlEncode="False"
            DataFormatString="<a target='_blank' href='https://{0}'>{0}</a>"
            HeaderText="Customer - link" />
    </Columns>
```